# Вернуть идентификатор новой записи, и заполнить его для объекта task

Tags: c#, sql-server

Нужна срочная помощь... В данном коде требуется вернуть идентификатор новой записи, и заполнить его для объекта task.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Записывает в базу данных созданную задачу
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="task"></param>
    public async Task CreateAsync(TaskDl task)
    {
        using IDbConnection db = Connection;
        db.Open();
        await db.ExecuteAsync(@"
        INSERT INTO Tasks (
        UserID, TargetID, Name, StartDate, EndDate, Discription) 
        VALUES(
        @UserID, @TargetID, @Name, @StartDate,@EndDate, @Discription)", 
        task);}
```

Я предполагаю что id получаем с помощью `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, но второе условие что нужно заполнить его для `task`, кто может знает как решить данный вопрос?

Comment: [Execute Insert command and return inserted Id in Sql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18373461/312041)

Comment: Так выложите ваше решение как ответ

Comment: извините ввел в заблуждение, не работает это, посмотреть бы реализацию с использованием `async await`... вопрос остается открытым

Comment: output inserted.id (если поле id является автоинкрементным)